# Why does every document in doc center go to the drop off library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-organizer, document-center, content-organizer-rule, drop-off-library

I currently have 1 rule setup for my content organizer. I'm curious as to why when I upload a document that follows the rule it always uploads to both the document center and the doc library that the rule is based on. Based on my understanding of the drop off library the documents should only go there if more than one rule applies to a specific document. Does anyone have an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you have two copies of the document? One in the destination library and one in the drop off library? How are you putting the documents in the record center? Are you uploading them there directly or using a send-to connection?

Comment: To clarify, the drop off library should only have documents that don't match any rule.  If a document matches multiple rules it will be routed according to the first match it encounters. In fact, doc centers often have a "catch-all" rule as the last rule.

Comment: @DerekGusoff I am getting 2 copies of the document when I upload to the document center. It is placing 1 in the drop off library and the other is placed in the proper folder based on the rule.

Where would I find the catch-all rule so I can disable it?

Comment: That is very strange, I have never seen that. How are you pushing the files to the document center? Is it progammatic, using a send-to connection or manually?

Comment: @DerekGusoff currently its manually. I go to the homepage of my document center and I hit the "Upload a document" web part that was added by default when I created the site. I then select the file I want to upload and then hit "okay". Once that is complete I fill out the form that pops up so that the content organizer can properly place my document in the correct folder. Once I hit submit on the form i get this message The document was submitted successfully. Its location will change pending action from a site administrator.
For now, you can continue to access the document here:

Comment: @DerekGusoff Then if I go to my proper folder and the drop off library the file is in both locations.

Comment: @DerekGusoff I think I figured out my problem and I believe it has to do with me miss reading the description of one of the content organizer settings.  

users are redirected to the Drop Off Library when they try to upload content to libraries in this site that have one or more content organizer rules pointing to them.  

My original understanding of this sentence was that if a document is uploaded that follows multiple rules it would be placed in the drop off library. After rereading it, I believe it is saying that if a library has multiple rules than uploaded docs will go to the (cont.)

Comment: Drop off library. Which in my case my library has multiple rules but each doc I upload can only follow one of these rules. Let me know if we have the same understanding of this. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure. I would suggest using a test environment and building out your solution, and testing, one small step at a time to see where the problem lays. You have a misconfiguration somewhere, you're going to have to systematically root it out.